# Not able to get selected item in wx.DataViewCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I am using wx.DataViewCtrl of wxpython 2.7.8 to list my data. I can get selected item from list using wx.DataViewCtrl:GetSelections() at first time by clicking menu. after closing the box by clicking close button, again am trying to open this box by clicking menu. But i coudn't get selected item to delete/modify using wx.DataViewCtrl:GetSelections(). wx.DataViewCtrl:GetSelections() returns empty list. But still the wx.DataViewCtrl box displaying the list of data.

Please help me. I am struck with this issue for last two days.Thanks in advance.

```
    class MainFrame(wx.Dialog):

def __init__(self, parent, title, data):

    self.data = data
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(800, 400))
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)       
    self.model = UpdateModel(self.data)



def createEntityTable(self, editor_ctrl):
    self.__editor_ctrl = editor_ctrl.getEditor()    
    self.dvc = dv.DataViewCtrl(self.panel,
                               style=wx.BORDER_THEME
                               | dv.DV_ROW_LINES # nice alternating bg colors
                               #| dv.DV_HORIZ_RULES
                               | dv.DV_VERT_RULES
                               | dv.DV_MULTIPLE, size = (600, 400)
                               )
    self.dvc.AssociateModel(self.model)

    self.dvc.AppendTextColumn("Name",  0, width=170, mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE)
    self.dvc.AppendTextColumn("DTD",   1, width=80, mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE)
    self.dvc.AppendTextColumn("File name",   2, width=80,  mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE)
    self.dvc.AppendTextColumn("Public Id",   3, width=80,  mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE)
    self.dvc.AppendTextColumn("Notation",   4, width=80,  mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE)

    for c in self.dvc.Columns:
        c.Sortable = True
        c.Reorderable = True

    self.new = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "New")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddRow, self.new)

    self.modify = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Modify")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onModifyRow, self.modify)

    self.delete = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Delete")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDeleteRows, self.delete)

    self.close = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Close")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClosePanel, self.close)

    dvcSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
    dvcSizer.Add(self.dvc, 1, wx.EXPAND)    

    btnbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    btnbox.Add(self.new, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    btnbox.Add(self.modify, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    btnbox.Add(self.delete, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    btnbox.Add(self.close, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5)
    dvcSizer.Add(btnbox, 0, wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, 5)

    self.panel.SetSizer(dvcSizer)
    self.ShowModal()


def OnDeleteRows(self, evt):
    items = self.dvc.GetSelections()
    rows = [self.model.GetRow(item) for item in items]
    self.model.DeleteRows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you used the DVC_IndexListModel from the wxPython Demo. Did you implement the method `DeleteRows(self, rows)` as shown in the `TestModel` derived from `PyDataViewIndexListModel`? This would be your `UpdateModel`.

BTW, 2.7.8 should be your (C)Python version. I suppose you have a wxPython version > 2.9.